# Sending multiple data with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an ajax request to a php file:

**php file**

```
$html .= '
<div class="col-md-4 select_icon_fa"> 
    <i id="id'. $result->id .'" class="fas fa-cart-plus cart_icon select_cart_plus" onClick="add_to_cart(\'' . $result->id . '\', \'add\')"></i>
  <select class="select" id="qty' . $result->id . ' ">
    <option value="1">value</option>
    ';  
    for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
        $html .= '              
        <option>' . $i . '</option>
        ';
    }
    $html .= '  
  </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function add_to_cart(id,type) {
    alert(id);
    var qty = jQuery('#qty' + id).val();
    if (qty > 0 ) {
        alert(qty);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo AJAX_FETCH_DATA ?>",
            type: 'post',
            data:'id='+id+'&qty='+qty+'&type='+type,
            success: function(result) {
                swal("success");
            }
        });
    } else {
        swal("Error", "error");
    }
}
```

**console**

```
id=17254&qty=undefined&type=add
```

**html edit - output**

```
<select class="select" id="qty17256 ">
                <option value="1">value</option>
```

The problem is that second value qty is `undefined` (`alert(qty);`), if is undefined - cannot send to php file. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: look like in your foreach not set value in option

Comment: Can you `console.log($('#qty' + id))` and check if the element is being selected?

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen Added html output value is 1

Comment: @aloha that would matter since the text will be taken as value if value is not set

Comment: @Mantykora7 Look at the space at the end `id="qty17256 "` it the problem

Comment: @AjithGopi, yes, im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Ajith Gopi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787922/9037945) and [aloha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787787/9037945) solved this problem.

This combine two problem to cause this issue.

First one is due to `option` doesn't have `value` attribute, so it won't able to return any value not matter which option be selected.

Second one is because select's `id` attribute has a extra space. So in fact, this element should call by `$('#qty17256 ')`. (Please noticed that space.)

[image]

Those two nice user has solved this post together, and I just wanna help you to understand how it work.

Cheers.

Comment: Just mentioning something hoping it would be useful to someone: If the value attribute is not specified, the option text will be considered as the value. Any how, it is a good practice to specify value explicitly as @aloha mentioned

Comment: If an option does not have a value, it will just take the text and use as value. Also I don't see the point in this answer. It has already been said but those 2 people and there is no reason to combine them because they are easy to understand.

Comment: Also the only problem in the OP's code is the  space

Answer (score 2):

It seems your have an extra space for the id attribute (in the end) please remove that space from php.

Comment: I do not believe:)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this line :

```
<select class="select" id="qty' . $result->id . '">
```

It removes the whitespace at the end of the `id` attribute.

It seems that whitespaces are not allowed here

Comment: Matthieu this is a comment not an answer, I know you don't have enough rep to post comments, but you should not make comments in the answer section.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen he needs more reputation to comment, it seems...

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen oh sorry, my bad... I didn't see that 